# Django is giving me an "invalid date format" error when running tests despite specifying date format in settings

Tags: python, django, django-models, datefield, django-validation

My settings file has these settings:

```
# settings.py
USE_L10N = False
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%m/%d/%Y']
```

In my test file, I'm creating an object requires a date and looks like this:

```
# tests.py
my_model = Thing(a_date='11/22/2019').save()
```

When I run the test, however, the test gets stuck when it goes to create the object and throws the error:

> django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'11/22/2019' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]

Is there something I'm missing? Why would it be throwing this error?

Comment: How is your Thing model structured in `models.py`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`, as `DATE_FORMAT` sets how Django displays the date.

Change your code with:

`DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%m/%d/%Y']`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` is relevant for `Forms` but not for `Models`.

An (invalid) ticket regarding the same problem was raised [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27364).

Comment: Well, not on the model level but on the form level. So e.g. if a user enters the date in one of the defined formats in a ```ModelForm``` and the form is saved, all is fine. If you try to create a model directly in you program using those formats it will not work. Let me put it this way: DATE_INPUT_FORMATS is for user interaction

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `USE_L10N` is set to `FALSE`.

(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-format)

Also see: [How to change the default Django date template format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737146/how-to-change-the-default-django-date-template-format)

Comment: I added `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%m/%d/%Y']` and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Are you sure the settings file is being found and applied?  (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927394/django-settings-not-working-correctly)

But Chris may have a point with the `Forms` but not `Models` issue (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27364).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need ad date_input_format read [there](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#date-format) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53437913/django-datefield-format-impossible-to-validate-and-save-to-model)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error while testing one of my views.

```
# settings.py
DATE_FORMAT = '%d.%m.%Y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d.%m.%Y', '%d-%m-%Y', '%d/%m/%Y', '%d/%m/%y', '%d %b %Y',
                      '%d %b, %Y', '%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y', '%d %B, %Y',
                      '%d %B %Y']

# forms.py
last_examination = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(
    attrs={
        'value': False,
        'class': 'datepicker',
        'data-date-format': 'dd.mm.yyyy',
        'data-date-autoclose': 'True',
    }
))
```

For a test I setup this data:

```
# test_views.py
cls.data2 = {'1-last_examination': date(day=19, month=2, year=1972),
                 '1-last_examination_result': 'OK'}

def test_Input2View_POST(self):
    self.c = Client()
    response = self.c.post(url, data=self.data2)
```

which raises a ValidationError `Enter a valid date.`
Therefore the settings.py don't apply for this test, which was also stated by Chris comment.

Quick fix for this is hardcoding the correct date format, e.g. in my case

```
# test_views.py
cls.data2 = {'1-last_examination': '19.02.1972',
                 '1-last_examination_result': 'OK'}
```